# How to preserve filters on Kendo Grid refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

The following command will refresh the grid if I change a property

```
   $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh()
```

However I notice that my filtering is ignored. For example I have a status column that changes when the user clicks a button and the template image reload after using the refresh method. However, the current filter status is ignored so the item updates in the grid when it should disappear because of the filter. Is there a way to preserve the filtered items?

Solution:

```
var filters = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(); 
$("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").refresh(); 
$("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(filters);
```

Comment: I found the solution but if there is an alternative feel free to share. Thanks!
var filters = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter();
$("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
 $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(filters);

Comment: You should not need to save filters before the refresh. It should actually work without it. `refresh` does not remove filtering conditions.

Comment: This is from ancient times but . . . it's the 'refresh()' that is unnecessary.  The Grid will be rerendered (again) when the 'filter(filters)' completes.  'filter()' with no parameters returns the current filters which you need when you call it the second time.  If anything, I think you could do it all in one statement like: $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter());